# how to create a dynamic reports java/j2ee

Tags: jakarta-ee, jasper-reports, reporting, birt, dynamic-reports

I have a specific needs in reporting for my project, i wont to let the client choose the columns to be shown, and he can also choose a restriction for dates or integers ... (for example he wont to report customers where their ages between 18 and 25), and effectively we should have joined tables.

I goggled that and i found [dynamic reports](http://www.dynamicreports.org/) and [Birt report](http://eclipse.org/birt/), but they only respond for the first constraint (choose the columns to be shown).

can anyone help me if there is other products, or if i can use Birt for my needs?

I wont a solution like [JasperSoft](https://www.jaspersoft.com/fr)

Comment: BIRT can do all this but your question is not specific enough. You should for example post a sample report-design of what you tried so far

Answer (score 0):

With BIRT we can achieve following

> Choosing Columns : Yes
>   Selecting ages between certain group  : Yes
>   Joining tables : Yes

**So yes.. BIRT can be used !**

Comment: the choose should be dynamic, after deployment the client can Select ages between certain group for example

Comment: Yes. Achievable !  BIRT supports inclusion of Javascript code with HTML .